# The target entry-point "@angular/material/slider" has missing dependencies:

Tags: angular, angular-material

The target entry-point "@angular/material/slider" has missing dependencies:

- @angular/cdk/a11y
- @angular/cdk/bidi
- @angular/cdk/coercion
- @angular/cdk/keycodes
- @angular/cdk/platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run    `npm i @angular/cdk -d` command at CLI

Comment: Don't forget to add a -d (making the command `npm i @anglar/cdk`, that way if you need to start over, it'll be accessible through `npm i`. I cannot recommend using the `ng upgrade` script enough, though - adding material is as simple as `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: Thanks. And yes adding material is simple.