# How do I resolve missing dependencies for @angular/material

Tags: angular, angular-material-7

I have an angular project that, up till now, would build and run successfully.  I wanted to add a modal and came across some articles about [building a dialog with Angular Materials](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/).

The problem comes when I run ng serve.  I get an error:

```
    PS C:\Users\my_directory> ng serve
    file:///C:/Users/my_directory/source/repos/Timesheet%20angular/Timesheet%20angular/ClientApp/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/bundles/chunk-DJRTTRF3.js:941
          throw new Error(`The target entry-point "${invalidTarget.entryPoint.name}" has missing dependencies:
                ^
    Error: The target entry-point "@angular/material" has missing dependencies:
     - @angular/cdk/a11y
     - @angular/cdk/coercion
     - @angular/cdk/bidi
     - @angular/cdk/keycodes
     - @angular/cdk/overlay
     - @angular/cdk/portal
     - @angular/cdk/scrolling
```

I have tried to reinstall angular material and cdk (`npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk` ), I found [this solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828608/the-target-entry-point-angular-material-slider-has-missing-dependencies) but running the command `npm i @angular/cdk -d` did not fix the problem.

Here is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "timesheet_angular",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
        "start": "run-script-os",
        "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44440 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
        "start:default": "ng serve --port 44440 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build:ssr": "ng run Timesheet_angular:server:dev",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.4",
        "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/localize": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-server": "~13.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
        "run-script-os": "^1.1.6",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.1.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
        "@angular/cli": "^14.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "typescript": "~4.4.4"
      }
    }
```

Here is the HTML and TS files for the modal I'm trying to build

```
    <h2 mat-dialog-title> {{ description }} </h2>
    
    <mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">
    
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput
               placeholder="Course Description"
               formControlName="description">
      </mat-form-field>
      ....
    
    </mat-dialog-content>
    
    <mat-dialog-actions>
      <button class="mat-raised-button" (click)="close()"> Close</button>
      <button class="mat-raised-button mat-primary" (click)="save()"> Save</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
```

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from "@angular/material";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dialog',
      templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
    })
        export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    openDialog() {

    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, dialogConfig);
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `package.json` and `node_modules` folder, then running `npm install` ?

Comment: I tried that yesterday and ran into a number of error for missing modules.  I think I solved some of them but now I have a "Cannot find module typescript".  I've tried a couple times to install with `npm install -g typescript` but the error persists.

Comment: I've made it work in some [MCVE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kp7y2w), could you give it a look ? Maybe copy the package.json from there

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails...reboot!  I uninstalled everything and reinstalled, and now it works.  hmph!